# How get return value of java spring boot method to Angular 8

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to show the return value of a java method in the angular frontend. I'm a beginner to angular 8.  I cannot find the problem.
here my result.page.html

```
<h1 style="text-align: center; color: darkred">{{predictionResult}}</h1>
```

Here is my result.page.ts

```
predictionResult: any;
getPrediction() {
    this.predictionService.getPrediction().subscribe((result) => {
      this.predictionResult = result;
      return this.predictionResult;
    });
  }
```

here the predictionService.ts
'''

```
getPrediction(){
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(`http://localhost:8080/getResult`, this.restCallsService.getRequestHeaders());
  }
```

and here the controller

```
    @PostMapping("/prediction")
    @GetMapping("/getResult")
    public ResponseEntity getResult(@RequestBody QuestionDto questionDto) throws IOException {
        float responseInt;
        httpUtils httpUtils = new httpUtils();

        String response = httpUtils.sendPostRequest(
                "[["+questionDto.getQuestion1()+","+questionDto.getQuestion2()+","+questionDto.getQuestion3()+","+questionDto.getQuestion4()+","+questionDto.getQuestion5()+","+questionDto.getQuestion6()+","+questionDto.getQuestion7()+","+questionDto.getQuestion8()+","+questionDto.getQuestion9()+","+questionDto.getQuestion10()+"]]");

        responseInt = Float.parseFloat(response);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(responseInt);
}
```

I want to display the respontInt value in the result.page.html. Any help would be really appreciate. thank you

Comment: why does your endpoint has POST and GET at the same time ?

Comment: remove @PostMapping("/prediction"). It is not required as you are already doing a post call inside the getResult() method